# Search processes from task manager consume CPU% even after suspending the search service.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I have suspended the search service using the below command

```
Suspend-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication –Identity “Search Service”
```

Yet, i see search related services (search component) is consuming CPU. Is that the default behavior or is there a process to suspend it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is default behavior. For our patching we have a script that stops those services explicitly after suspending the search application.
(The script is not mine but I lost the original reference to the author)

```
$srv4 = get-service "OSearch15" 
$srv5 = get-service "SPSearchHostController"

if($srv4.status -eq "Running") 
  { 
    $srch4srvctr = 2 
    set-service -Name "OSearch15" -startuptype Disabled 
    $srv4.stop() 
  }

if($srv5.status -eq "Running") 
  { 
    $srch5srvctr = 2 
    Set-service "SPSearchHostController" -startuptype Disabled 
    $srv5.stop() 
  }
```

Comment: You use this script after pausing the search? and do you have any script post resuming the search to start above services?

Comment: Yes exactly, pause search, stop services, patch and start afterwards. I found the reference article that I took the script from: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2013/04/01/why-sharepoint-2013-cumulative-update-takes-5-hours-to-install/